# Making columns resizable in bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 and it is great but Is there any way I can add certain columns another class like resizable and maybe add min-width or max-width and they will be resizable within these limits. That would be so great.

I’m not referring to any existing library specifically. I am just looking for a solution to this problem.

An example code would be:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col" resizable style="max-width:500px;"></div>
    <div class="col" resizable></div>
    <div class="col" style="min-width:100px;"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Thank you very much

Comment: @ZimSystem not sure why you want to mix jquery ui with bootstrap that just seems like a headache waiting to happen.

Comment: @Eonasdan I don't want to mix jqueryUI and Bootstrap but maybe rturkek wants to use jQueryUI for resizable component.

Comment: No I was looking for a method to solve this problem. I do not have any reference to jquery or jqueryui resizable. Split.js look promising so far. Testing...

Comment: Yes, OFC you can use whatever you want.. i was just letting you know there's nothing built in to Bootstrap 4 for resize. And you do have jQuery if you're using Bootstrap because it's required. jQueryUI is separate. I have used jQueryUI, split.js and plain old JS for various resizing implementations in the past.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Split.js just worked perfect for me, If you are using flex (bootstrap 4) you also must add elementstyle and gutterstyle attributes.

This is how I did it

HTML:

```
    <div class="row no-gutters" style="height:300px">
        <div id="one" class="col">A</div>
        <div id="two" class="col">B</div>
        <div id="three" class="col">C</div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.split {-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;overflow-y: auto;overflow-x: hidden;}
.gutter {background-color: transparent;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: 50%;}
.gutter.gutter-horizontal {cursor: col-resize;background-image:  url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAeCAYAAADkftS9AAAAIklEQVQoU2M4c+bMfxAGAgYYmwGrIIiDjrELjpo5aiZeMwF+yNnOs5KSvgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='); }
.gutter.gutter-vertical {cursor: row-resize;background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB4AAAAFAQMAAABo7865AAAABlBMVEVHcEzMzMzyAv2sAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAABBJREFUeF5jOAMEEAIEEFwAn3kMwcB6I2AAAAAASUVORK5CYII='); }
.split.split-horizontal, .gutter.gutter-horizontal { height: 100%;float: left;}
```

JS Library :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/split.js/1.3.5/split.min.js"></script>
```

Code:

```
var splitobj = Split(["#one","#two","#three"], {
    elementStyle: function (dimension, size, gutterSize) { 
        $(window).trigger('resize'); // Optional
        return {'flex-basis': 'calc(' + size + '% - ' + gutterSize + 'px)'}
    },
    gutterStyle: function (dimension, gutterSize) { return {'flex-basis':  gutterSize + 'px'} },
    sizes: [20,60,20],
    minSize: 150,
    gutterSize: 6,
    cursor: 'col-resize'
});
```

Comment: Why `no-gutters`? Still true in Bootstrap 4.1 or is there a better way now? If not, can you show how to restore the gutters in css?

Comment: lol you kinda stole my answer but glad to see you got it working :)

Comment: Can each column width be initially set using a fixed flex-basis and controlled via CSS? For example flex: 1 1 300px;? TIA!

Comment: So is this compatible with col-sm-4 and those grid classes?

Comment: I got it working in bootstrap 4 by additionally overriding the max-width in the elementStyle function with the same value as the flex-basis value.

Answer (score 12):

> https://split.js.org/

You can use split js you'd give your elements an id and set default sizes, because you're using bootstrap you already have a dependency on Jquery so that shouldn't be an issue.

Github link is: https://github.com/nathancahill/split

```js
const GUTTER_SIZE = 30;

const gutterStyle = dimension => ({
  'flex-basis': `${GUTTER_SIZE}px`,
});

const elementStyle = (dimension, size) => ({
  'flex-basis': `calc(${size}% - ${GUTTER_SIZE}px)`,
})

Split(['#one', '#two'], {
  sizes: [500, 100],
  minSize: 200,
  elementStyle,
  gutterStyle
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 170px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/split.js/1.3.5/split.min.js">
</script>
```